# Restore .img backUp...but is 1MB too big

Tags: backup, restore, raspberrypi

I done with Disks a backup *.img*.
I'm trying now to restore it but I found this message:

[image: errorMessage]

Could someone please tell what I done wrong?
I  formatted with Disks and Gparted but I always get the same result.

Comment: I think you have to select the block device `/dev/mmcblk0` instead of the partition `/dev/mmblk0p1` as the destination.

Comment: By the button in the corner of the windows in the picture (top-right) i found the way to restore on /dev/mmcblk0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restore the image you have to select the block device `/dev/mmcblk0` instead of the partition `/dev/mmblk0p1` as the destination.